# Route path definition problem in React-Router-Dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When defining the router path in `react-router-dom` v5, there was no problem in the form of `"www.test.com/researcher=:id"`. I saw that there was a problem when I upgraded to v6. I don't want to take it as a parameter by splitting according to `"="` after the slash, or I don't want to do `"www.test.com/researcher/:id"` this way. How can I solve it?

`"www.test.com/researcher=:id"`

I want to use this way in v6.

Comment: `researcher=:id` is a strange url format, normally it would be in the pathname `researcher/:id` or querystring `researcher?userId=:id`, maybe they aren't handling it as it's non-standard. What's your reason for doing a non-standard url format?

Comment: I need to use this format. because there are a lot of pages indexed by google. there is also external access by linking to these pages. the path of all of them will have to change.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *partial* dynamic path segments in `react-router-dom@6`. Generally you use a path like `"/researcher/:id"` or place the id value in the URL search string, e.g. `"/researcher?id=...."`.

If you want to match a dynamic path segment that has an id value with prefix `"researcher="` then the ***entire*** segment needs to be a dynamic path segment identifier and the component will need to do some basic string manipulation.

See [Dynamic Segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) for more details.

Example:

Given `<Route path="/:researcherId" element={<Researcher />} />`

```
const Researcher = () => {
  const { researcherId } = useParams();
  const [researcher, id] = researcherId.split("=");

  // check researcher and id values

  ...
};
```